# Mysql How to update n rows using count function?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

In the following table, I want to set delete = true if the total records for same orgid exceed 500
and I want to do it according to createdate such that if records exceed 500 the old records get deleted and make total records 500 for that orgid.

here is my table

```
Table A
+----+-------+------------------+--------+------------+
| id | orgid | transactionvalue | delete | createdate |  
+----+-------+------------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |     1 |              123 | false  | 05-16-2020 |  
|  2 |     1 |              412 | false  | 07-16-2020 |  
|  3 |     2 |              762 | false  | 07-16-2020 |  
+----+-------+------------------+--------+------------+
```

Here is the query I am trying

```
update A 
set 
  delete = true 
where orgid = 1 
and (select count(*) as records 
      from (select * 
            from A order by createdate
    ) as pseudotable)) >500
```

Comment: You could clarify and simplify by providing sample data for 3 companies (5 each) keeping 2.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @EricBrandt 8.0.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try all of the other answers, they might be correct but this is what worked for me

```
update A 
set `delete` = true 
where orgid = 1 AND id IN (
SELECT id FROM  A where orgid = 1
order by createdate DESC
LIMIT 500,18446744073709551615);
```

Answer (score 1):

use subquery and join update

```
   UPDATE tablea
            INNER JOIN
        (select orgid, count(*) cnt from tablea group by orgid
        ) b ON tablea.orgid = b.orgid 
    SET 
        delete = 'true'
    where cnt>500
```

Comment: Createdate has to feature here somewhere surely?

Comment: order by createdate desc ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to find the 500th record for each org and then use that information:

```
update tablea a join
       (select a2.org_id, a2.created_date as cutoff_created_date
        from (select a2.*,
                     row_number() over (partition by a2.org_id order by create_date desc) as seqnum
              from tablea a2
             ) a2
        where a2.seqnum = 500
       ) a2
       on a.org_id = a2.org_id and and
          a.created_date < a2.cutoff_created_date
    set delete = true;
```